# WCF service data members get null value when get a call from client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that holds local data members.
When the service get a call from the client the data members value is null.
The only way I find to solve it is to set the data members to static.
Can someone explain why the members get null value and if there another way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of the InstanceContextMode you are using, or the one set by default (which is per session).

If you set the InstanceContextMode to Single (or Per Session if polled by the same client instance), only one instance of your WCF service will be instantiated and thus your instance members will be intact unless they are changed in your code somehow.

This instance will be accessed by the clients depending on the concurrency mode.

Check this article for more information:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/3-ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per

You have the modes :

Per call

Per Session

Single